# Is there a way to enable s3proxy trace logs

Tags: s3proxy

We are using s3proxy and facing issues so to get more info we are trying to check if we can enable trace logs in s3proxy

Comment: How are you running s3proxy ? Did you check the existing env variables ?

Answer (score -1):

To enable trace logging, you need to modify the logging configuration in the S3Proxy properties file. Locate the logback.xml file in the root of your S3Proxy installation directory, and add the following lines to enable trace logging:

```
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty" level="TRACE" />
<logger name="org.jclouds" level="TRACE" />
```

These lines will enable trace level logging for the Jetty and jclouds libraries used by S3Proxy. You can adjust the logging level as needed, depending on the level of detail you require.

Once you have modified the logback.xml file, restart the S3Proxy server for the changes to take effect. You should then see more detailed logs in the server console or log files, which can help you diagnose the issues you are facing.

Comment: Which lines needs to be added ?